# Image sequence with pan gesture algorthm

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, algorithm, uiimageview

I have 100 images (a400e3x_0.png ,....., a400e3x_98.png, a400e3x_99.png).
These images changes according to swipe on the UIImageView, like animation that user can control.
The problem is when user stops panning and then starts again, the animation goes back to image 0. I need to save the position when user stopped panning, and I can do it. But when I add It the addition is always there. Example: I stopped panning at Image 16, then I start again from 16, when (curX%100) is zero it still adds the 16 always. Can you please help me with algorithm for this.

```
- (IBAction)PanGesAction:(id)sender
{
 CGPoint translation = [_PanGes translationInView:self.view];
 int curX = (int)translation.x;
 addition = (curX%100)+Savedif;

 NSLog(@"%d", addition);

 [_ImageV2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"a400e3x_%d.png", addition]]];


    if (_PanGes.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        NSLog(@"End");
        Savedif = addition;
        //When user end

    }

    if (_PanGes.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        NSLog(@"Began");
         //When user begin

    }
}
```

Comment: You already detect `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`, why not use that to decide how to manage your `addition` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a new gesture starts you have the opportunity to edit the values that it's going to send you, so we can transfer your starting value to the gesture and keep things simple:

```
- (IBAction)PanGesAction:(id)sender
{
    if (_PanGes.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        NSLog(@"Began");
        //When user begin
        [_PanGes setTranslation:(CGPoint){Savedif, 0} inView:self.view];
        Savedif = 0;
    }

    CGPoint translation = [_PanGes translationInView:self.view];
    int curX = (int)translation.x;
    addition = (curX%100);

    NSLog(@"%d", addition);

    [_ImageV2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"a400e3x_%d.png", addition]]];


    if (_PanGes.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        NSLog(@"End");
        Savedif = addition;
        //When user end
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx! I've been stuck with this for hours!

Answer (score -1):

There is a way that you don't have to save anything,

Introducing the `transform` property in `UIView`,

Try this code:

```
- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    UIView *imageView = gesture.view;
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint transition = [gesture translationInView:gesture.view];
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageView.transform.tx + transition.x, imageView.transform.tx + transition.y);
        [gesture setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:gesture.view];
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        imageView.center = CGPointMake(imageView.center.x + imageView.transform.tx, imageView.center.y + imageView.transform.ty);
        imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    }
}
```

The imageView's position is always:

```
imageView.center.x+image.transform.tx
imageView.center.y+image.transform.ty
```

You can act on it accordingly.